# SQL: how to filter results beyond GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

### Original question

> The following relations keep track of airline flight information:
>
> **Aircraft** (*aircraft_number*, aircraft_make, cruisingrange)
>
> **Certified** (*pilot_id*, *aircraft_number*)
>
> **Pilot** (*pilot_id*, pilot_name, salary)
>
> Note that *italic* attributes denote primary keys. In this scheme every pilot is certified for some aircraft. Write each of the following queries in SQL Format.
>
> > (ii) Find the names of pilots who can operate planes with a range greater than 2,000 miles but are not certified on any Boeing aircraft.

Can someone help me understand how to write a query for this?

My guess would be to first `join PILOT` to `CERTIFIED`, then `join` to `AIRCRAFT`, then `GROUP BY PILOT.pilot_id`, but beyond that, I am not sure how to filter the `pilot_id` to exclude those without at least one plane with a minimum 2000 cruising range and with no aircraft of the `aircraft_make` 'Boeing'?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code or steps you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it.

Comment: Please, don't post (links to) images of text or code. When the link gets broken, nobody can use this question. Furthermore, text is more useful, when copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
select p.pilot_name
  from pilot p
  join certified c
    on p.pilot_id = c.pilot_id
  join aircraft a
    on c.aircraft_number = a.aircraft_number
  where a.cruisingrange > 2000
    and p.pilot_id not in (
          select c.pilot_id
            from certified c
            join aircraft a
              on c.aircraft_number = a.aircraft_number
            where a.aircraft_make = 'BOEING'
        )
  group by p.pilot_id
```

Comment: Thanks Georgi for your reply! However, I think I might be interpreting the question a little differently. Supposed pilot 'Tom' is certified on 2 planes of the make 'Boeing' and 'Airbus' respectively. Assuming both planes have a cruising range of > 2000, your query would return 'Tom' (which should not be returned because Tom has a 'Boeing' plane, despite the fact that he also has a non-'Boeing' plane). Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Thanks Georgi this makes perfect sense!